# reference request: Riesz/Newton potential and HLS inequality in L1.logL1

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, potential-theory

Let's consider in dimension $d\geq 3$ the Newton/riesz potential $f=I_2[g]$
$$
f(x)=\int_{R^d}\frac{1}{|x-y|^{d-2}}g(y)dy,
$$
which solves $-\Delta f=g$ (up to positive normalizing constants, which I shall ignore).

The classical [Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood%E2%80%93Sobolev_inequality#Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood.E2.80.93Sobolev_lemma) inequality guarantees that
$$
|f|_{L^q(R^d)}\leq C|g|_{L^p(R^d)},\qquad q=\frac{dp}{d-2p}
$$
as soon as $g\in L^p(R^d)$ for some $p\in (1,d/2)$.

If $g$ is only in $L^1$ the naive guess $|f|_{L^{d/(d-2)}}\leq C|g|_{L^1}$ fails, but we know that the singular integral converges for almost every $x\in R^d$ and that there is a weak type estimate
$$
\forall \lambda\geq 0, \qquad\mathcal{L}(\{x:\,|f|(x)\geq \lambda\})\leq C\left(\frac{|g|_{L^1}}{\lambda}\right)^{d/(d-2)}
$$
($\mathcal{L}$ denoting the usual Lebesgue measure on $R^d$).

**My question is the following**: what can we say if $g$ is in the slightly better space $g\in L^1\log L^1$, i-e if $|g|.|\log(|g|)|\in L^1(R^d)$? I don't think we can expect $f\in L^{d/(d-2)+\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, but maybe $f\in L^{d/(d-2)}\log L^1$ or something like that? I would expect at least some improvement and in particular $f\in L^{d/(d-2)}$, but maybe not.

Thank you in advance for your comments and input.

**PS:** I wrote my question in dimension $d\geq 3$ for simplicity, but I'm also interested in the borderline case $d=2$ when the Poisson kernel $1/|x-y|^{d-2}$ is replaced by $-\log|x-y|$.

Comment: This paper of O'Neil seems to study this problem systematically: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1965-115-00/S0002-9947-1965-0194881-0/

Comment: Thank you @Terry Tao, it looks like this is exactly what I need!

Comment: Also, could anyone please recommend a standard reference for the related  problem of (fractional) integration with measure data, typically $-\Delta u=\mu$ in the whole space?

Comment: Maybe "Analysis" by Lieb and Loss would suit you?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, I'm writing it since nobody commented on your question. You might want to check Yano's extrapolation theorem (see [here](http://www.mat.ucm.es/serv/revmat/vol18-1/vol18-1e.pdf) for a nice exposition) which states that: if an operator $T$ is bounded on all $L^p$ for $p>1$ close to 1, and the norm grows at most like $(p-1)^{-1}$, then $T$ extends to a bounded operator on $Llog L$. Not exactly what you are asking, but this might give you some ideas to get started.

Comment: Thank you Piero, this looks promising and I will check it out.