# Minimizing some $H^{-1}$ functional over (a subset of) probability densities in $R^d$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

Let me consider the following subset of probability measures in $R^d$
$$
\mathcal{K}_M=\left\{0\leq u(x)\in L^1(R^d):\quad \int u(x)dx =1,\,\int|x|^2u(x)dx\leq M,\,\int u(x)|\log u(x)|dx\leq M\right\}
$$
for some fixed $M>0$. For given $u\in \mathcal{K}$ let me define $\Psi=(-\Delta)^{-1}u$ the Newton potential, i-e up to multiplicative constants
$$
\Psi(x)=G*u(x)=\int \frac{1}{|x-y|^{d-2}}u(y)dy\qquad \text{a.e. }x\in R^d
$$
where $G(z)=\frac{1}{|z|^{d-2}}$ is the usual Poisson kernel. On this admissible set the functional is defined as
$$
u\in \mathcal{K}_M\mapsto F[u]=\int |\nabla \Psi(x)|^2dx,
$$
where possibly $F[u]=\infty$ if $\nabla \Psi\notin L^2$. This is roughly speaking a squared $H^{-1}$ norm of $u$.

**Goal:** show that there is a minimizer $u^*\in \mathcal{K}_M$
$$
F[u^*]=\min\limits_{u\in \mathcal{K}_M}F[u].
$$

**What I have so far:** since my functional is bounded from below there is a minimizing sequence $\{u_n\}_n\subset \mathcal{K}_M$. By the Dunford-Pettis theorem and easy arguments that I shall not detail here, it is possible to show that there is some $u^*\in \mathcal{K}_M$ such that $u_n\rightharpoonup u^*$ in $L^1(R^d)$. Now by definition of my functional we have that $\nabla\Psi_n\rightharpoonup \Phi^*$ in $L^2(R^d)$ for some $\Phi^*\in L^2$ with $|\Phi^*|^2_{L^2}\leq \liminf |\nabla\Psi_n|^2_{L^2}=\inf\limits_{u\in \mathcal{K}_M}F[u]$. So if I could show that $\Psi_n\to\Psi^*$ in some sense and if uniqueness for solutions to the Poisson equation $-\Delta \Psi=u$ holds, I may conclude that $\Phi^*=\nabla\Psi^*$ with $\Psi^*=(-\Delta)^{-1}u^*=G*(u^*)$ and I would be done.

**The problem:** from [this other post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169197/reference-request-optimal-lp-regularity-for-solutions-to-delta-u-f-with) it seems that $u\in L^1$ is unfortunately a borderline case for the Poisson equation: if $u$ is only in $L^1$ then $\Psi$ is not in $L^p(R^d)$ for any $p\geq 1$ (the problem seems to be the decay at infinity). In order to get compactness of $\{\Psi_n\}$ I cannot hope to use a naive argument like: "$|u_n|_{L^1}=1\Rightarrow |\Psi_n|_{L^p}\leq C$, then extract a weakly $L^p$ converging subsequence with $\Phi^*=\nabla\Psi$, and conclude by uniqueness that $\Psi=G*(u^*)$". Since $|u_n|_{L^1}=1$ some extra information is provided by the [Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood.E2.80.93Sobolev_lemma), which guarantees here that the sequence $\Psi_n$ is bounded in the [Lorentz/weak $L^p$ space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Weak_Lp) $L^{\frac{d}{d-2},\infty}(R^d)=L^{\frac{d}{d-2}}_{weak}(R^d)$. So everything essentially boils down to compactness in $L^{\frac{d}{d-2}}_{weak}(R^d)$ and uniqueness for Poisson equation within this class of solutions for $L^1(R^d)$ data.  Let me point out that by the very setting of the problem $\nabla \Psi_n$ is bounded in $L^2$, which should help (is there any kind of Sobolev/interpolation inequality for $\Psi$ in Lorentz spaces and $\nabla \Psi$ in classical $L^q$ spaces?). Also I actually have that $\{u_n\}$ is bounded in  $L^1\log L^1$, which is very slightly better than just $L^1$.

This question is also related to these [post 1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169197/reference-request-optimal-lp-regularity-for-solutions-to-delta-u-f-with), [post 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159497/uniqueness-for-poisson-equation-in-rd-with-mildly-regular-data), [post 3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159313/reference-request-riesz-newton-potential-and-hls-inequality-in-l1-logl1). I've been unsuccessfully trying to solve this problem for the last couple of weeks, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why is uniqueness for $-\Delta \Psi = u$ with $u\in L^1(R^d)$ an issue? If I have two solutions $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ of the equation, both in the sense of distributions (so $\Psi_{1,2}$ only need be $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$), then the difference $\Psi=\Psi_1-\Psi_2$ satisfies $\Delta\Psi=0$ in the sense of distributions. Then $\Psi$ is $C^\infty$, as can be seen by regularizing $\Psi$ by convolution. If $\Psi$ is bounded and harmonic, then it is constant ... Maybe the boundedness of $\Psi$ is the issue?

Comment: Actually, @piero-dancona says it much nicer as an answer to your other question at http://mathoverflow.net/a/159500/16530.

Comment: @Mark: yes, I remember Piero's nice answer. This decay at infinity condition was my first thought too. I would totally agree with you if I had "decay at infinity" in the form $\Psi_{1,2}\in L^p$ for some $p\geq 1$. However here the $\Psi$'s are not in $L^p(R^d)$ for any $p$, but only in weak-$L^p$/Lorentz as in my OP. I'm not familiar at all with those spaces and I'm certainly missing an obvious point, but let me ask 2 questions nonetheless (probably trivial): 1) does $\Psi\in L^p_{weak}$ imply any "decay at infinity", and 2) if so is that decay condition sufficient to guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: @Mark: also, this would only settle half of the problem, namely uniqueness. But what about compactness, which would be here $\Psi_n\to\Psi$ in some sense for some $\Psi\in L^{\frac{d}{d-2}}_{weak}$?

Comment: Yes, if a function $f$ is in $L^p_{weak}(R^d)$, then any truncation $f$ to a finite range (e.g. $(f\vee -1)\wedge 1$) is in $L^q(R^d)$ for $q>p$. This follows from the property that the distribution function satisfies $\lambda_f(t) \leq \|f\|_{p,weak}^p t^{-p}$ and  the layer-cake principle (e.g. Lieb-Loss Sec 1.13).

Comment: I just realized that your case is slightly better than the standard $L^1$-right-hand-side case, since you have bounded $\|\nabla \Psi_n\|_2$ by construction. By the Sobolev inequality that implies that $\Psi_n$ is bounded in $L^{d/(d-2)}$ and you can extract a weakly converging subsequence. Then you can pass to the limit in your equality $\Psi_n = G*u_n$ after integrating against a test function.

Comment: I guess you meant $\Psi_n$ bounded in $L^{d^*}=L^{2d/(d-2)}$ (critical Sobolev exponent), right? I tried this approach by cutting of $\Psi_{n,k}=(\Psi_n\vee -k)\wedge k\in L^q$ for all $q>p=d/(d-2)$ and $|\nabla \Psi_{n,k}|_{L^2}\leq |\nabla \Psi_n|_{L^2}\leq C$ to apply the standard Sobolev inequality and conclude that $|\Psi_{n,k}|_{L^{2d/(d-2)}}\leq C |\nabla\Psi_{n,k}|\leq C$, hence $|\Psi_n|_{L^{2d/(d-2)}}\leq C$ by letting $k\to\infty$. However in dimension $d=3$ the exponent $\frac{d}{d-2}=3> 2$ so the classical Sobolev inequality is not clear to me (see next comment).

Comment: (previous comment, continued) For example given $f\in L^{q}$ with $q\in (2,2^*)$ and $\nabla f\in L^2$ does the Sobolev inequality $|f|_{L^{2^*}}\leq C |\nabla f|_{L^2}$ hold? If $q\leq 2$ this is clear, but if $q>2$?

Comment: My bad: it will hold of course by density of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c$, since the standard cutoff/mollification $f_n=\zeta_n (f*\rho_n)\to f$ in any $L^q$ as long as $f\in L^q$, while $\nabla f_n\to \nabla f$ in any $L^p$ as long as $f\in L^p$. So your agument works just fine, thanks Mark!